# Four & Five season tent questions

Tags: discussion

My opinion is that these should be merged after Beta, but not before.

The problem is that a novice or uneducated person will google 4 season tent, get the five season link and not even read If the site is to be a resource it's primary purpose has to be to provide answers people can find, in priority over nice tight categorization.

After beta, perhaps we should merge these, or fix the five season question to match the answer, so that when the title comes up in google, it more accurately reflects the information the user will receive.

[In what conditions is a four-season tent needed?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/3139/in-what-conditions-is-a-four-season-tent-needed)

[What's the difference between a 2, 3, 4, and 5 season tent?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/1833/what-is-a-5-season-tent)

Comment: Why only after beta? We can fix the 5-season question now?

Comment: @gerrit -- That's one reason for putting it up here.  My experience is that heavy pruning during beta discourages growth, while a more permissive policy encourages growth up until permissive means you are allowing "bad" members (ie, lots of attitude, spam, etc.).  Closing lots of questions in beta discourages people from asking.  The theory is that "quality brings quantity" but my experience is that "quantity of decent quality" bring the quantity necessary to achieve critical mass, at which point on can prune to stricter quality standards.

Comment: @gerrit -- I misunderstood your comment.  Yes, we should fix the 5 season question title.